# Getting the percentage of how much areas intersects with another using GeoPandas

Tags: python, geometry, geopandas, spatial-join, geodataframe

I have two GeoPandas dataframes, namely:

1. `grid` - the base map that contains a grid of 100x100 meter squares.

[image: Grid Map]

2. `land` - the land use of an area (e.g. farmland, meadow, etc.).

How do I, upon spatially joining both, create an extra column that would show the percentage of how much a specific `land` attribute intersects? For example:

```
  square  geometry     land    percentage
0      A    POLY..     farm           .40
1      A    POLY..   meadow           .60
```

Square A from `grid` intersects with both a farm and a meadow from `land`, and shows the percentage of how much those land types overlap with a 100x100 square.

What I have so far is simply the joining function, as I do not know how to approach getting the "percentage" column:

```
final = gpd.sjoin(grid, land, op='intersects', how='inner')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`overlay`](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html) operations. Here's a quick example using some fake data.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

# Creating the GeoDataFrame with the grid geometries
grid_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data={'grid_id':[101,102,103,104],
                                  'grid_cat':['W','X','Y','Z'],
                                  'geometry':[Polygon([(1,5),(3,5),(3,3),(1,3)]),
                                              Polygon([(3,5),(5,5),(5,3),(3,3)]),
                                              Polygon([(1,3),(3,3),(3,1),(1,1)]),
                                              Polygon([(3,3),(5,3),(5,1),(3,1)])]},
                            geometry='geometry')
grid_gdf['area_grid'] = grid_gdf.area
grid_gdf.plot(column='grid_id')
```

[image: grid_gdf]

```py
# Creating the GeoDataFrame with the land geometries
land_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data={'land_id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                                  'land_cat':['A','B','C','B','C','A','C','A','B'],
                                  'geometry':[Polygon([(0,6),(2,6),(2,4),(0,4)]),
                                              Polygon([(2,6),(4,6),(4,4),(2,4)]),
                                              Polygon([(4,6),(6,6),(6,4),(4,4)]),
                                              Polygon([(0,4),(2,4),(2,2),(0,2)]),
                                              Polygon([(2,4),(4,4),(4,2),(2,2)]),
                                              Polygon([(4,4),(6,4),(6,2),(4,2)]),
                                              Polygon([(0,2),(2,2),(2,0),(0,0)]),
                                              Polygon([(2,2),(4,2),(4,0),(2,0)]),
                                              Polygon([(4,2),(6,2),(6,0),(4,0)])]},
                            geometry='geometry')
land_gdf['area_land'] = land_gdf.area
land_gdf.plot(column='land_id')
```

[image: land_gdf]

```py
# Performing overlay funcion
gdf_joined = gpd.overlay(grid_gdf,land_gdf, how='union')

# Calculating the areas of the newly-created geometries
gdf_joined['area_joined'] = gdf_joined.area

# Calculating the areas of the newly-created geometries in relation 
# to the original grid cells
gdf_joined['land_area_as_a_share_of_grid_area'] = (gdf_joined['area_joined'] / 
                                                   gdf_joined['area_grid'])

# Aggregating the results
results = (gdf_joined
           .groupby(['grid_id','land_cat'])
           .agg({'land_area_as_a_share_of_grid_area':'sum'}))

# Printing results
print(results)

#                   land_area_as_a_share_of_grid_area
# grid_id land_cat                                   
# 101.0   A                                      0.25
#         B                                      0.50
#         C                                      0.25
# 102.0   A                                      0.25
#         B                                      0.25
#         C                                      0.50
# 103.0   A                                      0.25
#         B                                      0.25
#         C                                      0.50
# 104.0   A                                      0.50
#         B                                      0.25
#         C                                      0.25
```

When adapting to your case, you'll likely want to change column names used for each operation, but you can probably understand the gist of what's going on.